# Can I edit compressed files using sudo?

Tags: sudo

Vim has the ability to transparently decompress files while editing them. The way I understand it, it copies the file to a temporary directory, decompresses it there, and opens the decompressed version instead.

Sadly, this does not work when invoking `vim` via `sudo`:

```
$ whoami
a
$ sudo -u b vim /path/to/log.gz

# Inside vim:
"/path/to/log.gz" [noeol] 181009L, 44515536C
Error detected while processing function gzip#read:
line   44:
E484: Can't open file /tmp/v8kSqBW/1
line   47:
Error: Could not read uncompressed file
```

Checking the temporary directory, both the containing directory and the copied file belong to user `b`, so I'm not quite sure what's going on here. `chmod`ing the file and opening it as user `a` works as expected.

Is it possible to make the sudo invocation above work?

Read-only would suffice for my purposes, but read-write would be nicer.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I would try `sudoedit`/`sudo -e`, but idk if the native gzip editing has support for writing.

Comment: I can't use `sudoedit`: `editing files in a writable directory is not permitted`. Basically, the files are created without `g+rw` in a directory belonging to my user's group. And adjusting sudo settings is not a solution I could apply.